# How to create and use a lookup table

Tags: r

I have a character vector of misspelled words:

```
wordswrong <- c("veh", "crrts", "ornges")
wordscorrect <- c("vehicle", "carrots", "oranges")
```

Here's a dataframe:

```
words <- data.frame(terms = c("crrts oranges",
+                               "car is a veh", 
+                               "orngs bannas peas"))
```

How can I go through each word in words$terms and update based on my two vectors?

Comment: Try `for(i in seq_along(wordswrong)) words$terms <- gsub(wordswrong[i], wordscorrect[i], words$terms)` or `library(qdap); words$terms <- mgsub(wordswrong, wordscorrect, words$terms)`

Comment: Thanks @akrun! I'm sure I have a memory of once seeing code where someone used a lookup table along the lines of df$wrongwords <- lut (lookuptable). Does this sound familiar? Or maybe it's the wrong context for a list? Or perhaps since each cell is not an exact lookup I cannot go this route

Comment: Oh hang on, mgsub looks perfect! Cheers for the tip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `mgsub` from `qdap`

```
library(qdap)
words$terms <- mgsub(wordswrong, wordscorrect, words$terms)
```